# Django best practice for views.py files?

Tags: python, django, optimization, django-views

Large companies obviously have huge request loads and tons of information to render, so where in a Django project does that information get processed?

Does it happen in the views.py file? A separate .py file that's called by the views.py file?

I'm asking because my views.py files become thousands of lines long very quickly... does this matter or am I missing something here?

I have a couple of views in my project that processes a lot of data from the database, what is the best practice for where to put the code?

Comment: Most of the logic to transform a request into a response is done in the views yes. Request-unaware processing is done in the models. Normally however views are not that enormous, because one can use mixins, decorators, etc. to reuse logical components. Forms for example also remove a lot of boilerplate when validating, cleaning, and processing input data.

Comment: This is perfect - Ive never created mixins or decorators, when do I know when to build a decorator vs a mixin? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: We have published 70+ best practices to write scalable apps.

https://digiqt.com/blog/django-best-practices-for-scalable-apps.html